# Android: Duplicate @id issue while taking Signed Apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-install-apk

I am trying take signed APK for my android application. While trying to take signed APK am getting error

> Information:Gradle tasks [:appassembleRelease]
>   Error:(117) Error: Duplicate id @+id/tittle, already defined earlier in this layout [DuplicateIds]
>                       android:id="@+id/tittle"
>
> Error:(124) Error: Duplicate id @+id/tittle, already defined earlier in this layout [DuplicateIds]
>                       android:id="@+id/tittle"

uncheck alll the lint error checking and in the gradle add

> lintOptions {
>           abortOnError false
>       }

but still i cant generate signed APK because of duplication issue. There where 20 duplicate id is shown so rename all id is not possible.

Comment: Try to clean the project and then build the signed apk

Comment: i tried clean and rebuild the project, but still the issue is there @Sagar Trehan

Comment: post your layout which showing duplicate id error

Answer (score 0):

This line in your XML: `android:id="@+id/tittle"` sets the id of a view. The `+` in that line means to create a new id. I presume you have `@+id/tittle` somewhere else in your XML file which should be replaced with `@id/tittle` (without the plus) because you want to use the same id in that second position, not create a new one.

Also note that two views can't have the same id value.